# How to know if a variable is set in the view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'd like to know if there's a way to know if a variable exists in a view.

I'm creating a custom form's builder for my app theme and I'd like to include the `$errors` variable in a HTML tag. Any way to know if it's previously set in the view?

**Update**
I meant how to access a view var outside the view. How to access the $errors var from somewhere else, a package for instance.

I'm currently creating a custom form builder:

```
{{ MyFormBuilder::text('name', 'value', array()) }}
```

It should print

```
<input name="name" value="value" ... />
<p>ERRORS NAME REQUIRED</p>
```

The errors `<p>` tag only if an error found validating this field. I want to check from my `text()` function if there's an error in `$errors`.

I've tried using `global $errors` in my function, but it does not work...

I hope it's a bit more clear ;)

**Solved**
Using `Session::get('errors');` ;D
Thanks to @machuga.

Comment: @if(!empty($var)) or 
{{ $var or 'undefined' }}

Answer (score 15):

this should work

```
if(isset($var))
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking to the `$errors` variable that is returned by the `validator` class? If so, don't bother with the extra code to check if it exists.  From the L4 docs:

> Laravel will always check for errors in the session data, and automatically bind them to the view if they are available. So, it is important to note that an $errors variable will always be available in all of your views, on every request, allowing you to conveniently assume the $errors variable is always defined and can be safely used.

Simply checking `if( isset($errors))` will always return `true` in Laravel 4.

Comment: Thanks for this, useful. But still need other answer... Have a look to my update ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP's in-built function [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) for that purpose.

**Code:**

```
if( isset($errors) ){
//your code
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($errors) && !empty($errors)){
// your code here
}
```

Comment: `empty` also checks if a variable exists. So, `if (!empty($errors))` is enough

Answer (score 0):

You are using blade
Code:

```html
@if($var)
  --php code--
@endif
```